# HTML tag not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am outputting some information from my database using JavaScript. Some of this information includes HTML tags, such as `<sub>`. The error I'm getting in my browser is

> Invalid regular expression: missing /

My guess is that JavaScript is having a problem with the closing tag in `</sub>`. How can I make a forward slash work in javascript?

Here is some example code, in case you would need it:

```
echo "
<script>
function wikitoCalculator() {
    document.getElementsByName('chemicalsearch')[0].value = $name;
    var userChemical = document.getElementsByName('chemicalsearch')[0].value;
    if (userChemical.toLowerCase() === 'vatten') {
        var formel = $vatten3[namn2];
        var massa = $vatten3[molmassa];
        document.getElementById('formel').innerHTML = formel;
        document.getElementById('atommassa').innerHTML = massa;
    } 
}
</script>
";
```

As you can see, Im simply trying to output some information from a PHP variable that is taken from a database, through JavaScript into the HTML. Nothing is getting outputted, and Im getting the error stated above.

Comment: Can you post example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to wrap your php variables with string quotes. Your JavaScript is coming out like `myString = <sub> blah blah </sub>` when it should be `myString = "<sub> blah blah </sub>"`

Wrap your php variables in quotes `"$myVar"`

In your particular case it might be

```
document.getElementsByName('chemicalsearch')[0].value = "$name";
```

Comment: Just as you were writing this, I realised that this indeed was the problem :D Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome :) those get tricky as you mix three different languages haha.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this
`var formel = $vatten3[namn2];
 var massa = $vatten3[molmassa];`
This may work but I can't remember if double quotes allows arrays as well as primitive type variable either you should change to this.

`var formel = $vatten3['namn2'];
 var massa = $vatten3['molmassa'];`
You forgot the single quotes for the associative names in the array.

P.S. Sorry if the formatting is weird I'm doing this from my phone, I fix it as soon as I get to a computer.